# How to step into a service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I'm trying to step into a service. I'm able to step into it and debug it but if I'm calling it from a class it doesn't point at the service. I tried all the options that were previously mentioned but none of them worked for me(Attach to process, properties-> multiple startup projects-> pick start option for my service). Please advise.

Comment: I'm afraid if you don't tell us what *exactly* you did *in detail* we will not be able to tell you what you did wrong :(

Comment: Are you trying to attach to process with the actual code of the project? or you are trying to attach to a 3rd party service?

Comment: @NicoRiff I did Attach to Process then choose w3wp.exe process(IIS APPPOOL)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPgJq9G2zIA

Comment: @NicoRiff the link doesn't work

Comment: @nvoigt I working in asp.net c#, I have a project where one of the classes is calling a service. The service is in a completely different project. when i put breakpoint to debug the service from that class it doesn't point at the service but i can step into the service if i'm debugging it from the service project itself. I tried Attach to process in the service project but didn't work, I also tried the other option which is Properties and choose start for my service.

Comment: The "multiple startup projects" version should work. But I will not post *another* guide, because you probably made a mistake following the one you already have. And as long as you don't tell us which guide that is and what you did *in detail* the only thing we can do is shrug our shoulders and say "yeah, sucks, eh?". So please post details. What did you do? *Exactly*?